# Why server doesn't stop sending packets when client sends TCP RST multiple times?

Tags: tcp, wireshark, tcpdump

My device connects to the server which provides some video clips.
After connecting to the server, I check the wireshark and see there're multiple RST from client(port 40334) to server(80), but the server doesn't stop sending the packets.
I assume server should close the socket once client sends the RST.

After 10s, I see client start to use the other port(40520) and send HTTP GET to server, and client gets the MP4 packets successfully from server.

1. Why client sends multiple RST to server, and server doesn't stop sending the packets?
2. Why there's no ACK from client when receiving packets from server?

Thank you.

pcap screenshot 1 : Multiple RST from client 
[image]

pcap screenshot 2 : GET data from server normally. 
[image]

Log : https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gkt5c_WdLGYvZGMasrQLdP8a-RcQeqrt/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You filter for HTTP. The ACK package is not HTTP.

Answer (score 1):

I strongly suspect that the problem is you are setting `SEQ` to 1 and not giving it a number that corresponds even vaguely to your transfer.

From [RFC0793 (the TCPIP specification)](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc0793.txt)

> As a simple example of recovery from old duplicates, consider
>     figure 9.  At line 3, an old duplicate SYN arrives at TCP B.  TCP B
>     cannot tell that this is an old duplicate, so it responds normally
>     (line 4).  TCP A detects that the ACK field is incorrect and returns a
>     **RST (reset) with its SEQ field selected to make the segment**
>     believable.  TCP B, on receiving the RST, returns to the LISTEN state.

And

> Reset Processing
>
> In all states except SYN-SENT, **all reset (RST) segments are validated
>     by checking their SEQ-fields.  A reset is valid if its sequence number
>     is in the window.**  In the SYN-SENT state (a RST received in response
>     to an initial SYN), the RST is acceptable if the ACK field
>     acknowledges the SYN.
>
> The receiver of a RST first validates it, then changes state.  If the
>     receiver was in the LISTEN state, it ignores it.  If the receiver was
>     in SYN-RECEIVED state and had previously been in the LISTEN state,
>     then the receiver returns to the LISTEN state, otherwise the receiver
>     aborts the connection and goes to the CLOSED state.  If the receiver
>     was in any other state, it aborts the connection and advises the user
>     and goes to the CLOSED state.

So I would recommend that rather than setting `SEQ` to 1, set it to the last `SEQ` number you got, otherwise it is likely to be ignored as invalid.

An `RST` may not be honoured if the sequence or acknowledgement numbers are invalid.

> RST
>
> A control bit (reset), occupying no sequence space, indicating
>             that the receiver should delete the connection without further
>             interaction.  The **receiver can determine, based on the
>             sequence number and acknowledgment fields of the incoming
>             segment**, whether it should honor the reset command or ignore
>             it.  In no case does receipt of a segment containing RST give
>             rise to a RST in response.

Your client is being lazy, not properly resetting the connection and instead just trashes it and starts a new connection from another port.

Comment: Hi Mokubai, many thanks for your information. Furthermore, I have extra questions : 1. Does server is in the SYN_SENT state? 2. If client sends the RST with the correct SEQ, server will close the session successfully? 3. Why client sends RST to server in this case? Thank you.

Comment: Moreover, I consider client send RST with SEQ=1 is because server always includes the ACK=1.

Comment: ACK is a control bit/flag, not a request number, it can only have values of 0 and 1.  Please read the protocol specification I linked. Also https://osqa-ask.wireshark.org/questions/20423/pshack-wireshark-capture

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention clearly. ACK=1 means the Ack of server(ex. [ACK] Seq=11481 Ack=1). Because client doesn't send any packet, so the ack from server is 1 and client will send RST with bring Seq=1 to server.